# Jquery Reusable Code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some jquery code I'm using to set a div height based on its width. [JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/SGZfE/1/).

Everything works as is, but what I want is a function that is reusable, so that I'm not creating the exact same function for every unique id. The code is only good for the #bigHug div at the moment, but I want to be able to do something like `$('#biggerHug').setHeight(1.8)` in the `.ready` and `.resize` functions and to have the height set for the provided id.

I was attempting a solution by placing `$(this).width()` instead of `$('#bigHug').width()` in the `setHeight` function, but everything "broke". The div wouldn't show up on load or window resize. I was thinking it had to do with the `$(this)` referring to the `$(window).ready` instead of the `$('#bigHug').setHeight(1.8)`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function setHeight(ratio, elem ) {
    $elem = $(elem);
    var divWidth = $elem.width();
    var divHeight = divWidth / ratio;
    $elem.height(divHeight);
}


$(window).ready(function() {
    setHeight(1.8, '#bigHug');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight(1.8, '#bigHug');
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SGZfE/2/)**

Comment: Great! I tried this route too (i.e., adding the element as a variable), but I had missed some steps in the function. @lifo provided a nice solution if I'm intent on using the `$('#mydiv').setHeight(1.8)` syntax, but this is simpler for my use.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a jquery "[plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)" like this. *This is a simplistic example.*

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.setHeight = function(val){
        return this.each(function(){
            // do calculations here and assign height ...
            $(this).height(val);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You can then call it like this: `$('#mydiv').setHeight(1.8)` It'll work on any jquery selector, of course.

Comment: This is a great solution, but a little deeper than I need to dig presently. I appreciate your angle on keeping the suggested `$('#mydiv').setHeight(1.8)` syntax. Thanks! I'd check both answers if I could.